# Get the access_token and refresh_token using Azure AD with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-active-directory, access-token, refresh-token

I'm using this authetition [OmniAuth Azure Active Directory](https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory), I can login and logout from my application, but is not returning me a access_token and refresh_token and is necessary that I store this two information on my DB. When I try to get the access_token and refresh_token, rails return me this information:

[image]

There is one week that i'm trying to get the access_token and refresh_token, but nothing is working! I'll be really greatful if someone help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby) about building Ruby on Rails apps with Microsoft Graph. In the step of [adding Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby?tutorial-step=3), you'll notice there are two tokens in the hash generated by OmniAuth: `token`(access token) and `refresh_token`.

There is another example using Azure AD v2.0 Endpoint: [how to get a Microsoft Graph OAuth2 access token](https://www.example-code.com/ruby/microsoft_graph_oauth2_access_token.asp) from a desktop application or script.